# Using strcmp() to compare two arrays of C-strings

Tags: c++, c-strings

My project is to make a bank account program where the user enters an account number and a password to do anything within the program. The account numbers and passwords used must be stored as C-strings (the string header file is not allowed). I believe that the problem I am having is with the strcmp function. Here is my function where the problem occurs.

```
void get_password(int num_accounts, char **acc_num, char **password)
{
    char account[ACCOUNT_NUMBER];
    char user_password[PASS_LENGTH];

    std::cout << "\nEnter the account number: ";
//  std::cin.getline(account, ACCOUNT_NUMBER);
    std::cin >> account;

    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(account, *(acc_num + i)) != 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
            break;
    } while (i <= num_accounts);

    if (i == num_accounts)
    {
        std::cout << "\nCould not find the account number you entered...\nExiting the program";
        exit(1);// account number not found
    }

    std::cout << "\nEnter the password: ";
//  std::cin.getline(user_password, PASS_LENGTH);
    std::cin >> user_password;

    if (strcmp(user_password, *(password + i)) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\nInvalid password...\nExiting the program";
        exit(1);// incorrect password
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nAccount number: " << account
        << "\nPassword: " << user_password << "\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

acc_num and password are both arrays of C-strings. When I run/debug the program, it crashes at the first if statement. I guess my question is whether I'm using the strcmp function correctly or not, or if there is a problem with the pointers that I am using.

Comment: If the string header file is not allowed surely you can't use `strcmp()` either?

Comment: if you can't `#include <string>` did you `#include <cstring>` or `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: @EJP He probably meant `<string>` and not `<cstring>`.

Comment: You need to show how this function is called with the definition and initialization of each parameter.

Comment: i would always say `acc_num[i]` not `*(acc_num + i)`. It means the same thing but is more readable and idiomatic

Comment: @Jongware That was borderline vandalism. This is a question about the C++ language and by removing the C++ tag, you've totally changed the meaning of the phrase "the string header" in the question. (I've restored the correct tags, c++ and c-strings.)

Comment: @Jongware It's about C-style strings, hence the "c-strings" tag. It is not about the C language at all, hence there should be no "c" tag. This is clearly a C++ language question.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I have included the `<cstring>` header file, while the `<string>` header is not allowed. My question is about C-strings, not C++ strings.

Comment: How about asking the OP which string header s/he cannot use.   In C++, there are three distinct headers that might be referred to.  `<string>` which specifies `std::string` (among others), `<string.h>` which is the C header that declares functions like `strcmp()`, and `<cstring>` which is a C++ header that (loosely) provides the same functions as `<string.h>` but within namespace `std`.

Comment: @BlackRockCitizen To avoid such confusion in the future, do not use the "c" tag if your question involves code written in C++ (and to be compiled with a C++ compiler), even if that same code would also be legal C.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will run even when `num_accounts` is 0. Also, you're doing an out-of-bound array access by writing `while (i <= num_accounts);` instead of `while (i < num_accounts);`.

It would be better to write it like this:

```
while (i < num_accounts)
{
    if (strcmp(account, *(acc_num + i)) == 0)
    {
        // match found!
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What does 'ever after there are 0 accounts' mean? And it is not 'probable' but certain that he is looping once too often.

Comment: I meant that the loop will run even when `num_accounts` is 0 (which is unwanted I guess).

Comment: So fix your post to say so. At present it's meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming there is at least one account, and you're also looping once too often. A safer way to write it would be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_accounts && !strcmp(account, accnum[i]); i++)
    ;
```

or the corresponding `while` loop. A `do/while` is not appropriate here.